# Dynamically embed a logo in AS2

Tags: flash, load, actionscript-2, embed, dynamic

My problem is this: I have 16 x different sizes of flash files. (banners) That's 1 set. Now I have to make another 20 different sets with 20 different logo's in them.(320 banners total) So  the long and harse way to do this is open all 320 banners and then replacing the logo in them one by one.

My solution was to make 1 set and load a logo dynamically using the AS2 loadMovie function. But if I do that I have to have a logo image file in the same directory. My client doesn't accept this. He only wants flash files.

So, how do I embed a image dynamically on publish. So that if i'm finished with publishing  banners I can just throw the image away because it's in the flash file loaded already.

I've searched the net and could find thousands of tuts and explanations about dynamically images loading in AS2 but not dynamically embedding a image in AS2.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you convert the image to a swf, then load the swf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look into swfmill: http://swfmill.org

This allows you to generate swfs from xml files.

Check out the documentation here: http://swfmill.org/doc/using-swfmill.html